# Missing library that not exist: TCL86.LIB

Tags: opencascade

I have tried to compile OpenCascade on Win10 64bit, using VS2017. I compiled on 64bit, but I encounter a link errors, one of them is:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: TKDraw, Configuration: Debug x64 ------
1>LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'tcl86.lib'
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 9 failed, 50 up-to-date, 1 skipped ==========
```

I noticed that in project TKDraw, I have the following link settings files/path:

```
..\..\win64\vc14\libd\TKMesh.lib
..\..\win64\vc14\libd\TKService.lib
..\..\win64\vc14\libd\TKHLR.lib
C:\ActiveTcl\lib\tcl86t.lib
C:\ActiveTcl\lib\tk86t.lib
gdi32.lib
advapi32.lib
user32.lib
shell32.lib
..\..\win64\vc14\libd\TKShHealing.lib
opengl32.lib
windowscodecs.lib
C:\Program Files\freetype\lib\freetyped.lib
winmm.lib
..\..\win64\vc14\libd\TKTopAlgo.lib
..\..\win64\vc14\libd\TKGeomAlgo.lib
..\..\win64\vc14\libd\TKBRep.lib
..\..\win64\vc14\libd\TKGeomBase.lib
..\..\win64\vc14\libd\TKG3d.lib
..\..\win64\vc14\libd\TKG2d.lib
..\..\win64\vc14\libd\TKMath.lib
..\..\win64\vc14\libd\TKernel.lib
```

As you see, none of them tell me about **tcl86.lib**, but the compiler say that this lib is missing. Why ? Moreover, I didn't found any **tcl86.lib** in *opencascade* folder, so, why is asking  me about this file ? Can you help me a little bit ?

Answer (score 2):

You can download the 3rd party libraries for Open CASCADE here: https://old.opencascade.com/content/3rd-party-components

If you put all 3rd party libraries into one directory, you can state its location in the `CMake` build and the build will use them automatically.

Answer (score 1):

This is because Visual Studio C++ compiler has a `#pragma lib` feature allowing to add library dependencies directly in C++ code, see `src/Draw/Draw.cxx`:

```cpp
// on MSVC, use #pragma to define name of the Tcl library to link with,
// depending on Tcl version number
#ifdef _MSC_VER
// two helper macros are needed to convert version number macro to string literal
#define STRINGIZE1(a) #a
#define STRINGIZE2(a) STRINGIZE1(a)
#pragma comment (lib, "tcl" STRINGIZE2(TCL_MAJOR_VERSION) STRINGIZE2(TCL_MINOR_VERSION) ".lib")
#pragma comment (lib, "tk"  STRINGIZE2(TCL_MAJOR_VERSION) STRINGIZE2(TCL_MINOR_VERSION) ".lib")
#undef STRINGIZE2
#undef STRINGIZE1
#endif
```

Apparently, your Tcl/Tk build has an extra suffix "t" in library file name `tcl86t.lib`, so that linker is unable to find `tcl86.lib`.

Possible solutions:

- Rename `tcl86t.lib` -> `tcl86.lib` (the same for tk) in your Tcl installation.
- Comment/remove `pragma comment` in OCCT source code. As you are using CMake, it seems all libraries are already specified via project settings.
- Build Tcl/Tk from source code or use pre-built binaries without name deviations (as provided by [OCCT project](https://dev.opencascade.org/index.php?q=home/resources), for example).

Answer (score 1):

I got the same error trying to compile SQLite from source with MSVC. I saw no `#pragma` references to `tcl86.lib` in the source. However, I copied `tcl86.lib` in the Tcl directory, and renamed it to `tcl86t.lib`. It seems to work.

In the SQLite `crash8-1.2 test`, I am getting error:

> testfixture.exe: extra characters after close-quote while executing
> "sqlite3_crashparams"

I hope it's just a test problem.

Also, the build process gives errors if there are blanks in any of the directory names where the SQLite source has been unzipped.