# Compile OCCT7.5 with rapidjson using FreeCad Libpack?

Tags: compilation, rapidjson, opencascade, freecad

I'm looking to compile OCCT 7.5 in Windows 10 (x64 via VS2019) for use with FreeCAD, to enable exporting glTF files, which requires RapidJSON support (in OCCT). I've checked out OCCT 7.5.3 and RapidJSON 1.1.0 from their git repos, then grabbed the [FreeCAD libpack 12.5.2](https://github.com/apeltauer/FreeCAD/releases/tag/LibPack_12.5.2) (for OCCT 7.5). I started from [FreeCAD's build docs](https://wiki.freecadweb.org/Compile_on_Windows#Compiling_OpenCASCADE), then attempted to follow [OCCT's build docs](https://dev.opencascade.org/doc/overview/html/build_upgrade__building_occt.html#build_occt_windows).

When configuring the OCCT project in CMake-GUI, I've been able to find what I think are correct values for some variables (e.g. those regarding FREETYPE) within the FreeCAD libpack, as well as RapidJSON, but still get some errors in the config, seemingly no matter what values I try:

```
Could not find headers of used third-party products:
3RDPARTY_TCL_INCLUDE_DIR 3RDPARTY_TK_INCLUDE_DIR
...
Could not find DLLs of used third-party products: 3RDPARTY_TCL_DLL_DIR
3RDPARTY_TK_DLL_DIR
```

I've tried using *.lib, *.h and *.dll files found within the FreeCAD Libpack (and their corresponding directories) for *_LIBRARY/INCLUDE/DLL variables, but nothing is found. I see

```
Info: TCL is used by OCCT
Could NOT find Tclsh (missing: TCL_TCLSH)
```

even though `tclsh86t.exe` exists in the libpack/bin directory.

What should the 3RDPARTY_TCL_* & 3RDPARTY_TK_* CMake variables be set to, to use the FreeCAD libpack?

Comment: Does this help maybe: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65507149/2492801?

Comment: @BenjaminBihler It would, if I weren't using the FreeCAD libpack, since I already have it to build FreeCAD. Thanks, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was my lack of familiarity with CMake and Cmake-gui: the gui opened a dialog for a FILEPATH when specifying a PATH variable. I naively thought, "I don't know CMake, so I'll trust the gui". Totally wrong.

I manually edited the 3RDPARTY_* variable entries to point to the correct directories (or libs, when needed) in the FreeCAD libpack, using the variable name and description/hint for each to determine what the variable's value should be. Below are my entries, for reference:
[image]
I did need to check "Advanced", to edit the FREETYPE_LIBRARY_DEBUG & FREETYPE_LIBRARY_RELEASE variables (CMake set them to separate libs found in a jdk directory, presumably because it was added to the system path at some point).